# Use setter to validate parameter in constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor, setter

**Javascript**

Can setter used to validate parameter when creating new object, as seen on this code, the string input on numberOfStudents bypass the setter

```js
class School {
  constructor(name, level, numberOfStudents) {
    this._name = name;
    this._level = level;
    this._numberOfStudents = numberOfStudents;
  }

  get numberOfStudents() {
    return this._numberOfStudents;
  }

  set numberOfStudents(value) {
    if (isNaN(value)) {
      console.log('Invalid input: numberOfStudents must be set to a Number.');
    } else {
      return (this._numberOfStudents = value);
    }
  }
}

const primaryOne = new School('Primary One', 'L1', 'ten');
```

prints

> School { _name: 'Primary One', _level: 'L1', _numberOfStudents: 'ten' }

Please help

Comment: BTW, assignment automatically returns the value that was assigned, you don't need the return statement in the setter.

Answer (score 0):

You're bypassing the validation because you're assigning to the internal `_numberOfStudents` property. The setter is only run when you assign to `numberOfStudents`. So change the constructor to do that:

```js
class School {
  constructor(name, level, numberOfStudents) {
    this._name = name;
    this._level = level;
    this.numberOfStudents = numberOfStudents;
  }

  get numberOfStudents() {
    return this._numberOfStudents;
  }

  set numberOfStudents(value) {
    if (isNaN(value)) {
      console.log('Invalid input: numberOfStudents must be set to a Number.');
    } else {
      this._numberOfStudents = value;
    }
  }
}

const primaryOne = new School('Primary One', 'L1', 'ten');
```